# Quick method of shuffling a long array python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, random

Hi there Im looking to shuffle an array of 15 integers.  I can do this in a long winded manner i'm sure however I was wondering if there is a simple function to do this? i have tried importing random and using random.shuffle however it tells me it can only take a maximum of 3 positional arguments. Is there a function that can do this for a long array? Im struggling to find a way so far

```
 import random

a = random.shuffle(9,
6,
7,
5,
6,
8,
8,
9,
8,
6,
6,
7,
7,
7)

print(a)
```

Comment: please tag the appropriate language so people who are watching those tags can jump in to help. i'm assuming it's python

Comment: I suppose you need to put a _single_ parameter to `shuffle()` which is an array or a list, not _umpteen_ parameters.

Comment: Hi Sonnet , it should be taged? yes it is Python thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in array to the `shuffle()` method, something like this:-

```
import random
arr = [9,6,7,5,6,8,8,9,8,6,6,7,7,7]
random.shuffle(arr)
print(arr)
```

Hope this helps!